How to make the question about borderline clear?
Does a stable self actually exist in borderline people, especially artistic ones?
After getting explained that it was unclear what I was after with four different questions, I have cut the other to focus into one question, yet it still haven't received new feedback. I would like to hear your thoughts.
Before

Is this assumption correct? If yes, is there a way to know when their true self appears? Is that self called personality, and to know it it's required to have enough interaction with them? When they are acting chameleon, would a sudden appearance of an object or memory relating to the other self make them "switch" to normal? And by the way, what is the different between characteristic and personality?

After

Is this assumption correct? And by the way, what is the different between characteristic and personality? Is that self called personality?


I'm counting 6 question marks in the linked question - hence it is too broad because there is no focus and hence it is unclear what you are after. The help center describes some general guidelines how to ask focused questions. Focused questions tend to generate the best answers.

Come on, two of them are tag questions. They are there to contribute to the main ones (the one in title and the "is this assumption correct?", which are the same.) The last two are just quick definition question, which can be answered or not. I feel that anyone can answer the main one can quickly throw the answers of the two easy. And why don't you give me the feedback? I really want to improve it.

Relax. I am giving you feedback. A lot. I'm answering your questions here and giving lots of comments. I can't do more.

I've deleted all the tag questions and the minor ones. Can you check it again? Many thanks

Again, my comments go long...
Your question may be better received with some background information. 
A drastic example, but if I wrote a question "I assume red is green. Is this assumption correct?" would be closed on principle. It is the opinion of an individual, and would fall under the "behavior of individual" (ugh... "self-help") tag. Again (going back to the answer of another question), think about if "maybe you just think about this differently" could be given as an answer. If so, it would tend to fall under "behavior of an individual". Finding others who support or posit the view shows initial research and creedance (this is a real thing that people believe), and would certainly make a much stronger case for the question.

I've added a link for this. But having an opinion would fall under the "behavior of individual"? Isn't the point of asking a question (and the whole SE) is to ask for other's opinion?

At the end of the day, you are positing a viewpoint that no one else may share: "I think that they have, it just that they are not aware of it or it doesn't show up most of the time." This is what should be supported with links/citations/etc. And no: the community actively closes question where only opinion based answers are given (aka answers that cannot be supported with research, etc).
